# Forward DNS alias to other domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, alias

Is it possible to forward one DNS alias to another domain?
Example:
mysub.mydomain.com should return the IP Adresses of yoursub.yourdomain.org where mydomain and yourdomain are managed by the same Windows DNS server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you add a CNAME for mysub.mydomain.com that resolves to yoursub.yourdomain.org as outlined here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324260#5

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the DNS snap-in. To do this, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click DNS.
2. Under DNS, expand Host name (where Host name is the host name of the DNS server).
3. Expand Forward Lookup Zones.
4. Under Forward Lookup Zones, right-click the zone that you want (for example, mydomain.com), and then click New Alias (CNAME).
5. In the Alias name box, type mysub.
6. In the Fully qualified name for target host box, type the fully qualified host name of the DNS server on which IIS is installed. For example, type yoursub.yourdomain.org, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cname record is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that as far as most DNS requirements go... you may need to additional configurations.  I.e. for http traffic... frequently require the DNS name to serve pages from the website.  Since the FQDN won't match, you might not get the correct page.  You may need the other party to setup an alias to that site with your fqdn.  Otherwise, you'll need to setup your own site that redirects to the other.

A CNAME works the same as an A record, except that a CNAME points to a name, and an A points to an IP.  The URL won't automatically change because of a CNAME record.